# Execute code only if AJAX request takes a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In my web application, I'm using an `$.ajax()` request to load data from a database and display it in the browser. During the execution of the request, I display a `Loading Results ...` message like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loading-results-message').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loading-results-message').hide(); 
    }
});
```

This works fine. However, if there is not much data to load, the request takes only a fraction of a second. In this case, the message is only displayed for a fraction of a second as well. This animation happens so quickly that it's difficult to recognize it. Therefore, it would be great if it was possible to display the message only if the request takes a certain amount of time, i.e. some seconds at least but not only a fraction of a second. Is that possible somehow? By the way, I'm using Django on the server side, if that should matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to establish a timer, cancel the timer when the request completes:

```
var desired_delay = 2000;
var message_timer = false;
$.ajax({
    // ...
    beforeSend: function() {
        message_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#loading-results-message').show();
            message_timer = false;
        }, desired_delay);
    },
    complete: function() {
        if (message_timer)
            clearTimeout(message_timer);
        message_timer = false;
        $('#loading-results-message').hide(); 
    }
});
```

**Documentation**

- `setTimeout` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout
- `clearTimeout` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Comment: if the delay gets to close to the execution time you'll end up having the same effect! I would only delay the hiding function in order to last at least the minimum time to read the message.

Comment: If the script finishes before the timer, no message is displayed. That is the goal of the OP. If the script takes longer than the timeout, the message is displayed. If the timing is really close, there's nothing for it -- there is no "onAlmostComplete" event, or a means to determine if the request is about to return.

Comment: @Chris: I kinda want there to be a `onAlmostComplete` event now! :-P

Comment: @Chris Really nice, this is exactly what I wanted. :) Thanks! Just a minor issue: My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) says about the line `clearTimeout(message_timer)` the following: `Argument type Boolean is not assignable to parameter type Number.` Any idea what's wrong here? The code works, nevertheless.

Comment: @PeterStahl: That's because of type juggling!  `message_timer` starts as a boolean, but it changed to a number, and your IDE doesn't realize that the type does change.  You can just ignore it, or make `message_timer = 0` instead of `= false`.

Answer (score 0):

I am with @chris on this solution. But it might also be worth your while to look into http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

This will make it so you won't have to write the timeout for every single request.